# @ManyToMany with embedded class

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a problem with @ManyToMany - I have three classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_order")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OrderEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String status;
    private BigDecimal totalPrice;
    private Integer productsAmount;
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=OrderItemEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "order_item", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id"))
    public List<OrderItemEntity> orderItems;
}

@Embeddable
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OrderItemEntity {

    private Long quantity;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=ProductEntity.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private ProductEntity productEntity;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;
    private Long unitsInStock;
    private boolean active;
}
```

When I persists OrderEntity and then on another endpoint I call GET (/orders/{id}) I get the full information like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "status": "NEW_ORDER",
  "totalPrice": 10,
  "productsAmount": 1,
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "quantity": 1,
      "name": "test",
      "description": "test",
      "unitPrice": 10,
      "unitsInStock": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I want ONLY persist OrderEntity (method save from JPA) then as return I get null informations on product information like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "status": "NEW_ORDER",
  "totalPrice": 10,
  "productsAmount": 1,
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "quantity": 1,
      "name": null,
      "description": null,
      "unitPrice": null,
      "unitsInStock": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Persisting:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public OrderResponseDto save(OrderEntity orderEntity) {
    orderEntity = orderJpaRepository.save(orderEntity);
    return OrderEntityMapper.mapToResponse(orderEntity);
}

{
  "status": "NEW_ORDER",
  "totalPrice": 10,
  "productsAmount": 1,
  "orderItems": [
    {
      "quantity": 1,
      "productId": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyone can help and explain to me this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are missing the cascade configuration on `@ManyToOne` (by default to operations are cascaded to associated objects):

```java
@Embeddable
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OrderItemEntity {

    private Long quantity;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=ProductEntity.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private ProductEntity productEntity;
}
```

Comment: After this change I get: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.hexagonal.product.ProductEntity, when I change cascade to only Merge I get null values after save as well

Comment: Then you need to add also the code that actually persists the object to your question.